# Compute the limit of $n\cdot\left(\frac{\arccos\left(3/n^3\right)}{\arccos\left(3/(n+1)^3\right)}-1\right)$ when $n\to\infty$

Tags: limits

How to solve limit like this?

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}{n\left(\frac{\arccos\frac3{n^3}}{\arccos\frac3{(n+1)^3}}-1\right)}$$

$$=\lim_{n\to\infty}{n\left(\frac{\frac\pi2}{\frac\pi2}-1\right)}$$

$$=\lim_{n\to\infty}{n(1-1)} = 0$$
but $\infty*0$ is not define, how to solve it?

Comment: @gebruiker Horrible edit.

Comment: You can write 1 as arccos(0) and then do $cos^{-1}a+cos^{-1}b$ by making numerator same the above conversion isnt compulsory

Comment: @Did I disagree. I tried to reduce the height of the title, inspired by this thread: http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/9687/145141.

Comment: @gebruiker It might be desirable to reduce excessive heights of titles, but not if the result is mathematically ambiguous (and ugly, I would add).

Comment: @DavidM Sure the prefactor is not $n^4$ rather than $n$?

Comment: @Did I try understand your question, but I really don't understand what is prefactor?

Comment: @DavidM You asked about the behaviour of $n\cdot\left(\cdots\right)$, is it $n^4\cdot\left(\frac{\arccos\left(3/n^3\right)}{\arccos\left(3/(n+1)^3\right)}-1\right)$ instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can proceed as follows
\begin{align}
L &= \lim_{n \to \infty}n\left(\dfrac{\arccos\left(\dfrac{3}{n^{3}}\right)}{\arccos\left(\dfrac{3}{(n + 1)^{3}}\right)} - 1\right)\notag\\
&= \lim_{n \to \infty}n\left(\dfrac{\arcsin\left(\dfrac{3}{(n + 1)^{3}}\right) - \arcsin\left(\dfrac{3}{n^{3}}\right)}{\dfrac{\pi}{2} - \arcsin\left(\dfrac{3}{(n + 1)^{3}}\right)}\right)\notag\\
&= \frac{2}{\pi}\lim_{n \to \infty}n\left(\arcsin\left(\dfrac{3}{(n + 1)^{3}}\right) - \arcsin\left(\dfrac{3}{n^{3}}\right)\right)\notag\\
&= \frac{2}{\pi}\lim_{n \to \infty}n\arcsin\left(\dfrac{3}{(n + 1)^{3}}\cdot\sqrt{1 - \dfrac{9}{n^{6}}} - \frac{3}{n^{3}}\sqrt{1 - \frac{9}{(n + 1)^{6}}}\right)\notag\\
&= \frac{2}{\pi}\lim_{n \to \infty}n\arcsin f(n)\notag
\end{align}
The function $f(n)$ is algebraic and it is easily proved that $n f(n) \to 0$ and hence $n\arcsin f(n) = nf(n)((\arcsin f(n))/f(n)) \to 0 \cdot 1 = 0$ so the desired limit is $0$.

Answer (score 1):

This is just a naive thought, but have you tried the first order approximations $\arccos\left(\frac{3}{n^3}\right)\approx\frac{\pi}{2}-\frac{3}{n^3}$ and $\arccos\left(\frac{3}{(n+1)^3}\right)\approx\frac{\pi}{2}-\frac{3}{(n+1)^3}$ for $n\rightarrow\infty$? In this way the whole expression becomes
$$-\frac{18n^2+18n+6}{\pi n^5+3\pi n^4+3\pi n^3+(\pi+3)n^2},$$
whose limit is $0$ (as it should be).

Answer (score -1):

Suppose $A\to \infty$ and $B\to 0$ as $n\to \infty$. If you want to solve $\lim_{n\to\infty} AB$, you can rewrite it as $\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{A}{1/B}$ to get the indeterminate form $\frac{\infty}{\infty}$ in the limit, or as $\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{B}{1/A}$ to get the indeterminate form $\frac{0}{0}$ in the limit. Either of these can then be solved using L'hopital's rule.